# How to fix blury qpixmap in "Pyside2"

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to set qpixmap ,but it's blury in window.

```py
def set_image(self, source):
    self._avatar.setPixmap(QIcon(source).pixmap(QSize(100, 100)))
```

Comment: what is `source`?

Comment: `source` is the path of the image.

Comment: then use `self._avatar.setPixmap(QPixmap(source))`

Comment: def set_image(self, source):
      self._avatar.setPixmap(QPixmap(source).scaled(100, 100))

Comment: I'have Done, But still same problem.